# Why google Chrome performances are better when profiling?

Tags: google-chrome, three.js, profiling, webgl, google-chrome-devtools

This is something I've noticed when profiling my webGL game.

When devTool is open it is significantly more laggy (I guess because of all the debugging stuff)

However whenever I'm doing a profiling (CPU for instance but everything works) the performances rockets. 
In a heavy loaded scene it jumped from 11 fps to 40.

It has two resultant :

How can I get those performances at any time while devTool is open ?

I have a hard time debugging performances cause everything is working just crystal clear most of the time during profiling ...

Chrome 40.0.2214.115 m

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any logging to the console? It might be that profiling turning off some debugging stuff and thus performance returning to the initial values of FPS. If it is a reason, you will not be able to have the same performance with CDT and without it.

Can behaviour be repeated on the threejs examples like http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry? If yes, it's more serious issue. I was not able to repro such behaviour on Windows Chrome stable/canary versions.

Comment: nop no logging. Maybe profiling deactivate breakpoints ? It would explain that CDT doesn't need to check all the code states and steps ?

Comment: You are right. There are four agents which listen to the profiler state change. Here are: WebInspector.CSSStyleModel, WebInspector.DebuggerModel, WebInspector.DOMModel, WebInspector.WorkerTargetManager. Do you have many of entities any of these types? If it is WebGL app, it most likely doesn't have many neither CSS nor DOM entries. In case of breakpoints - does the slowdown depends on the number of breakpoints you set in the app?